# Pass parameter to PHP function through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, function

I have an ajax call on a WordPress website which looks like the following:

```
$('.stm-ajax-checkbox-button .button, .stm-ajax-checkbox-instant .stm-option-label input').click(function(e){

        if($(this)[0].className == 'button') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        var sold = '';

         if( $('.soldlistings').length ) {
             sold = '(true)';
         }  

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize() + '&action=stm_ajax_filter',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(this).closest('.stm-accordion-content-wrapper .stm-accordion-inner').addClass('loading');
                $('.stm-ajax-row').addClass('stm-loading');
                $('.classic-filter-row .filter-sidebar .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b').addClass('stm-preloader');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).closest('.stm-accordion-content-wrapper .stm-accordion-inner').removeClass('loading');
                $('.stm-ajax-row').removeClass('stm-loading');
                $('.classic-filter-row .filter-sidebar .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b').removeClass('stm-preloader');
                $('.classic-filter-row .filter-sidebar select').prop("disabled", false);

                if(typeof data.html != 'undefined') {
                    $('.stm-ajax-row .stm-isotope-sorting:not(.stm-isotope-sorting-featured-top)').html(data.html);

                    var sortVal = $('.stm-select-sorting select').select2('val');

                    $('.stm-ajax-row').removeClass('stm-loading');
                }

                stm_after_ajax_same_actions(data, sortVal);
            }
        })
    });
```

This then links to a PHP function (I won't paste the whole code) like so:

```
function stm_ajax_filter() {
}
```

I want to add a parameter to this function which I will then use to help work out where the Ajax call was used. To do this I have added a parameter to my PHP function. How do I set this parameter in the Ajax call?

Comment: By where it was used, do you mean something like the IP address of the client, or what page in your application it was called from?

Comment: Can you post the content of `ajaxurl`

Comment: What page it is on. I was going to put a div in on one page, do an if statement to see if it can be found and if it can, then set the parameter in the AJAX call to be true and if it can't, then don't set it.

Comment: The context of ajaxurl is http://{website}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add another parameter to the AJAX data property?

```
data: $(this).closest('form').serialize() + '&origin=mainPage&action=stm_ajax_filter',
```

And then in PHP you can just retrieve the 'origin' key.

```
$ajaxOrigin = $_GET["origin"];

// and then pass that variable to your function as an argument
stm_ajax_filter($ajaxOrigin);
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps in this line data: $(this).closest('form').serialize() + '&action=stm_ajax_filter',

i think you could try this:
data: $(this).closest('form').serialize() + '&action=stm_ajax_filter&your_variable='+parameter,